# get rectangle coordinates after detecting lines in image with open-cv python

Tags: python, opencv

In an image, one can detect the lines using `HoughLinesP` method in open-cv using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy.ndimage as ndi

img = cv2.imread(path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
smooth = ndi.filters.median_filter(gray, size=2)
edges = smooth > 180
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges.astype(np.uint8), 0.5, np.pi/180, 120)

for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    print(rho, theta)
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

# Show the result
cv2.imshow("Line Detection", img)
```

[image]

using the code and image as input the output will be like the image below:
[image]

By intersecting the vertical and horizontal lines, a few rectangles are created. How can I obtain the coordination of these rectangles?

Comment: You could try corner detection. See good features to track at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541

Comment: Continued from above. Draw your lines as 1 pixel wide white on black background. Then use good features to track to get the corners. Or from the line end points, compute the line equations and then find the intersections of every line with every other line.